# NGINX - AWS - LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, amazon-elb

i have to make a web application which a maximum of 10,000 concurrent users for 1h. The web server is NGINX.
The application is a simple landing page with an HTML5 player with streaming video from CDN WOWZA.

can you suggest a correct deployment on AWS?
LoadBalancer on 2 or more EC2?
If so, which EC2 sizing do you recommend? Better to use Autoscaling?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have to make a web application which a maximum of 10,000 concurrent users for 1h.

Avg 3/s, it is not so bad. Sizing is a complex topic and without more details, constraints, testing, etc. You cannot get a reasonable answer. There are many options and without more information it is not possible to say which one is the best. You just started NGINX, but not what it's doing (static sites, PHP, CGI, proxy to something else, etc.)

> The application is a simple landing page with an HTML5 player with streaming video from CDN WOWZA.

I will just lay down a few common options:

Let's assume it is a single static (another assumption) web page referring an external resource (video). Then the simplest and the most scalable solution would be an [S3 bucket hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) behind the CloudFront (CDN).

If you need some simple quick logic, maybe a lambda behind a load balancer could be good enough.

And you can of course host your solution on full compute (ec2, beanstalk, ecs, fargate, etc.) with different scaling options. But you will have to test out what is your feasible scaling parameters or bottleneck (io, network CPU, etc.). Please note that different instance types may have different network and storage throughput. AWS gives you an opportunity to test and find out what is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. The application is 2 page PHP and the impact is minimal because in PHP code i write only 2 functions that checks user/password and token.

the video is provided by Wowza CDN because is live streaming, not on-demand.

what tool or service do you suggest about the stress test of Web Server?